# Firestore documents with custom document IDs are not getting fetched

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

This is the Firestore collection with custom document IDs which are actually dates as string. The purpose of this kind of custom id is fetching the documents of particular date.

[image]

**Here's the code :**

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
                    .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
                    .collection("Bookings By Date")
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new 

OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: called");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: task result = " + task.getResult());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: task.getResult().getDocuments().size() = " + task.getResult().getDocuments().size());
                        QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots = task.getResult();

            }
        }
    });
```

[image]
Here are Logcatlogs where task.getResult().getDocuments().size() is returning **0** it should return **3** as i have 3 documents in the collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A document *can* actually be empty in Firestore, meaning that it *is* possible to have a document without data, and your code would load that.

In this case however, in your screenshot you can see that `1-4-2019` document name is is displayed in *italics*, which means that this document doesn't exist. The console merely shows this name in the list, because there are subcollections under that path. And since document `1-4-2019` doesn't exist, it won't be returned when you load all documents.

In short:

- A document can be empty, meaning that you *can* have a document without any data fields.
- All documents (including empty ones) *are* returned when you read all documents from a collection.
- If there are subcollections under a path for which no document exists, the Firestore console will show that non-existing document's title in italics.
- Non-existing documents are *not* returned when you read all documents from a collection.

Also see:

- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)
- [Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731794/why-are-non-auto-generated-document-ids-are-in-italics-in-firestore-console)
- [Parent document is being marked as "deleted" (italics) by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826365/parent-document-is-being-marked-as-deleted-italics-by-default)

Comment: Well, I could not even set the document fields programmatically. For this particular task where I can retrieve subcollections of a particular document by just referring its custom document ID, I had to use old school Firebase.

Comment: The code in your question shows nothing about writing. I answered your original problem, explaining why you get 0 documents when you read the documents from the collection. In addition I tried to explain why your fix may work, Firestore **can** read empty documents.

Answer (score 5):

Issue resolved. If a firestore document doesn't have any field in it then CollectionReferece#get() method skip those documents.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who can't get the document ID's of any collection make sure that you document has some fields. if it doesnot just add some fields to your doc and it will show you the doc ids.