# Why does Firebase colletion().getDocuments() return null or []?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called market and it had two documents that I can confirm in firebase.

[image]

I am now trying to get the number of documents in that collection like this:-

```
getAllItemsForSell()async {
    final snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('market').getDocuments();
    final documents = snapshot?.documents;

    print(documents); // []

  }
```

The above function prints out '[]', what am I doing wrong?
I looked everywhere on the internet but nothing seems to be helping.

please help? I am new to the Flutter Firebase world, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you expecting something different?  Empty array makes total sense for an empty collection, but we can't see if that's the case.  Please edit the question to explain what you are expecting, perhaps showing a screenshot of the documents you intended to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the number of documents in that specific collection try to get the documentId from users collection and iterate through it by passing it to market collection like this

```
 int sampleNum =0;
getAllItemsForSell()async {
        QuerySnapshot users =  await Firestore.instance.collection('market').getDocuments();
        for(DocumentSnapshot docs in users.documents){
          QuerySnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('market').document(docs.documentID).collection('marketPosts').getDocuments();
          sampleNum = doc.documents.length;
          //posts = doc.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
        }
        print(sampleNum.toString() +' **********');
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is working as expected.  Your "market" collection doesn't actually have any documents in it - it's completely empty.  When you see a document ID in italics in the console, that's means there is no document, but there are subcollections nested under that document.  The ID is there in the console so you can click through to them.

See also:

- [Parent document is being marked as "deleted" (italics) by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826365/parent-document-is-being-marked-as-deleted-italics-by-default)
- [Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731794/why-are-non-auto-generated-document-ids-are-in-italics-in-firestore-console)
- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use `Future<void>` or any type before the function. if it dosn't work read the doc for `FlutterFire` here is the link https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#document--query-snapshots
and i think just changing `getDocuments()` to `get()` it's maybe work,

```
Future<void> getAllItemsForSell()async {
    final snapshot = await 
    Firestore.instance.collection('market').getDocuments();
    final documents = snapshot?.documents;

    print(documents); // []

  }
```

Comment: I still get the same problem, and using 'get()' throws an error "The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'."